# Python Machine Learning - Imputing categorical data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, modeling, imputation

I am learning machine learning using Python and understand that I cannot run categorical data through the model, and must first get dummies.  Some of my categorical data has nulls (a very small fraction of only 2 features).  When I convert to dummies, then see if I have missing values it always shows none.  Should I impute beforehand?  Or do I impute categorical data at all?  For instance if the category was male/female, I wouldn't want to replace nulls with the most_frequent.  I see how this would make sense if the feature was income, and I was going to impute missing values.  Income is income, whereas a male is not a female.

So does it make sense to impute categorical data?  Am I way off?  I am sorry this is more applied theory than actual Python programming but was not sure where to post this type of question.

Comment: Dummies are replacing categorical data with 0's and 1's.  It also widens the dataset by the number of distinct values in your features.  So a feature named M/F will have values either 'male' or 'female'.  This in dummy form will be 2 columns.. male and female, with a binary 0 or 1 instead of text. This particular example also seems to introduce co-linearity because every time the male column is 0, the female is 1 and so on.

Comment: So, you just mean mapping M/F in a 1-hot type of encoding:
M -> [0, 1]
F-> [1, 0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answers depends on the properties of your features.

**Fill in missing data with [expectation maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) (EM)**

Say you have two features, one is gender (has missing data) and the other one is wage (no missing data). If there is a relationship between the two features, you could use information contained in the wage to fill in missing values in gender.

To put it a little bit more formally - if you have a missing value in gender column but you have a value for wage, EM tells you P(gender=Male | wage=w0, theta), i.e. the probability of the gender being male given wage=w0 and theta which is a parameter obtained with maximum likelihood estimation.

In simpler terms, this could be achieved by running regression of gender on wage (use logistic regression since the y-variable is categorical) to give you the probability described above.

Visually:

[image]

(these are totally add-hoc values but convey the idea that the wage distribution for males is generally above that for females)

**Fill in missing values #2**
You probably can fill in missing value using the most frequent observation if you believe that the data is missing at random even though there is no relationship between the two features. I would be cautious though.

**Don't impute**
If there is no relationship between the two features and you believe that the missing data might not be missing at random.